# Problem in creating new instance using the default constructor. The default constructor triggered an exception

Tags: java, jpa, glassfish, ejb

I'm having issues when trying to deploy my enterprise java bean application to GlassFish server 5.1.0. My errors are shown here:

```
  Exception while deploying the app [ED-EMS-SLSB]|#]
  Exception during lifecycle processing
org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: Exception [EclipseLink-28019] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.4.v20190115-ad5b7c6b2a): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Deployment of PersistenceUnit [ED-EMS-SLSB-ejbPU] failed. Close all factories for this PersistenceUnit.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.4.v20190115-ad5b7c6b2a): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.IntegrityException
Descriptor Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------
Exception [EclipseLink-168] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.4.v20190115-ad5b7c6b2a): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: Problem in creating new instance using the default constructor.  The default constructor triggered an exception.
Internal Exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Target Invocation Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(entity.EmsEmployee --> [DatabaseTable(EMS_EMPLOYEE)])
Runtime Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.createDeployFailedPersistenceException(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:908)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:313)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$2.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:427)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:486)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.iterateInitializedPUsAtApplicationPrepare(JPADeployer.java:468)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.event(JPADeployer.java:371)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:107)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:463)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:195)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:467)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:516)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:512)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:542)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:533)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1441)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:86)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1823)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1699)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:510)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:166)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:439)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:182)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:218)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:515)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
|#]
  Exception while deploying the app [ED-EMS-SLSB] : Exception [EclipseLink-28019] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.4.v20190115-ad5b7c6b2a): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Deployment of PersistenceUnit [ED-EMS-SLSB-ejbPU] failed. Close all factories for this PersistenceUnit.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.4.v20190115-ad5b7c6b2a): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.IntegrityException
Descriptor Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------
Exception [EclipseLink-168] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.4.v20190115-ad5b7c6b2a): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: Problem in creating new instance using the default constructor.  The default constructor triggered an exception.
Internal Exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Target Invocation Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(entity.EmsEmployee --> [DatabaseTable(EMS_EMPLOYEE)])
Runtime Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------
|#]
```

I'm hoping someone could shed some light on this as this is my first time dealing with Enterprise Java Beans and I find it to be very difficult, considering that everything has to be setup a certain way. If anyone can recommend something or point me in the right direction, that'll be great.

Edit:
This is my entity class EmsEmployee.java

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 *
 * @author jeremy
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMS_EMPLOYEE")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "EmsEmployee.findAll", query = "SELECT e FROM EmsEmployee e"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "EmsEmployee.findByEmpid", query = "SELECT e FROM EmsEmployee e WHERE e.empid = :empid"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "EmsEmployee.findByName", query = "SELECT e FROM EmsEmployee e WHERE e.name = :name"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "EmsEmployee.findByPassword", query = "SELECT e FROM EmsEmployee e WHERE e.password = :password"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "EmsEmployee.findByEmail", query = "SELECT e FROM EmsEmployee e WHERE e.email = :email"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "EmsEmployee.findByPhone", query = "SELECT e FROM EmsEmployee e WHERE e.phone = :phone"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "EmsEmployee.findByAddress", query = "SELECT e FROM EmsEmployee e WHERE e.address = :address"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "EmsEmployee.findBySecqn", query = "SELECT e FROM EmsEmployee e WHERE e.secqn = :secqn"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "EmsEmployee.findBySecans", query = "SELECT e FROM EmsEmployee e WHERE e.secans = :secans"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "EmsEmployee.findByBsbid", query = "SELECT e FROM EmsEmployee e WHERE e.bsbid = :bsbid"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "EmsEmployee.findByAccid", query = "SELECT e FROM EmsEmployee e WHERE e.accid = :accid"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "EmsEmployee.findBySalary", query = "SELECT e FROM EmsEmployee e WHERE e.salary = :salary"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "EmsEmployee.findByAppgroup", query = "SELECT e FROM EmsEmployee e WHERE e.appgroup = :appgroup"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "EmsEmployee.findByActive", query = "SELECT e FROM EmsEmployee e WHERE e.active = :active"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "EmsEmployee.findByMemo", query = "SELECT e FROM EmsEmployee e WHERE e.memo = :memo")})
public class EmsEmployee implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 6)
    @Column(name = "EMPID")
    private String empid;
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;
    @Size(max = 64)
    @Column(name = "PASSWORD")
    private String password;
    // @Pattern(regexp="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?", message="Invalid email")//if the field contains email address consider using this annotation to enforce field validation
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "EMAIL")
    private String email;
    // @Pattern(regexp="^\\(?(\\d{3})\\)?[- ]?(\\d{3})[- ]?(\\d{4})$", message="Invalid phone/fax format, should be as xxx-xxx-xxxx")//if the field contains phone or fax number consider using this annotation to enforce field validation
    @Size(max = 10)
    @Column(name = "PHONE")
    private String phone;
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "ADDRESS")
    private String address;
    @Size(max = 60)
    @Column(name = "SECQN")
    private String secqn;
    @Size(max = 60)
    @Column(name = "SECANS")
    private String secans;
    @Size(max = 6)
    @Column(name = "BSBID")
    private String bsbid;
    @Size(max = 10)
    @Column(name = "ACCID")
    private String accid;
    // @Max(value=?)  @Min(value=?)//if you know range of your decimal fields consider using these annotations to enforce field validation
    @Column(name = "SALARY")
    private BigDecimal salary;
    @Size(max = 15)
    @Column(name = "APPGROUP")
    private String appgroup;
    @Column(name = "ACTIVE")
    private Boolean active;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "MEMO")
    private String memo;

    public EmsEmployee() {
    }

    public EmsEmployee(String empid) {
        this.empid = empid;
    }

    public String getEmpid() {
        return empid;
    }

    public void setEmpid(String empid) {
        this.empid = empid;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getSecqn() {
        return secqn;
    }

    public void setSecqn(String secqn) {
        this.secqn = secqn;
    }

    public String getSecans() {
        return secans;
    }

    public void setSecans(String secans) {
        this.secans = secans;
    }

    public String getBsbid() {
        return bsbid;
    }

    public void setBsbid(String bsbid) {
        this.bsbid = bsbid;
    }

    public String getAccid() {
        return accid;
    }

    public void setAccid(String accid) {
        this.accid = accid;
    }

    public BigDecimal getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(BigDecimal salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public String getAppgroup() {
        return appgroup;
    }

    public void setAppgroup(String appgroup) {
        this.appgroup = appgroup;
    }

    public Boolean getActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(Boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    public String getMemo() {
        return memo;
    }

    public void setMemo(String memo) {
        this.memo = memo;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (empid != null ? empid.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof EmsEmployee)) {
            return false;
        }
        EmsEmployee other = (EmsEmployee) object;
        if ((this.empid == null && other.empid != null) || (this.empid != null && !this.empid.equals(other.empid))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "entity.EmsEmployee[ empid=" + empid + " ]";
    }
    
}
```

This is my stateless session bean class EmsEmployeeFacade.java

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package session;

import entity.EmsEmployee;
import entity.EmsEmployeeDTO;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

/**
 *
 * @author jeremy
 */
@Stateless
public class EmsEmployeeFacade implements EmsEmployeeFacadeRemote {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "ED-EMS-SLSB-ejbPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    private void create(EmsEmployee emsEmployee) {
        em.persist(emsEmployee);
    }

    private void edit(EmsEmployee emsEmployee) {
        em.merge(emsEmployee);
    }

    private void remove(EmsEmployee emsEmployee) {
        em.remove(em.merge(emsEmployee));
    }

    private EmsEmployee find(Object id) {
        return em.find(EmsEmployee.class, id);
    }

    private EmsEmployee myDTO2DAO(EmsEmployeeDTO emsEmployeeDTO) {
        EmsEmployee emsEmployee = new EmsEmployee();

        emsEmployee.setEmpid(emsEmployeeDTO.getEmpid());
        emsEmployee.setName(emsEmployeeDTO.getName());
        emsEmployee.setPassword(emsEmployeeDTO.getPassword());
        emsEmployee.setEmail(emsEmployeeDTO.getEmail());
        emsEmployee.setPhone(emsEmployeeDTO.getPhone());
        emsEmployee.setAddress(emsEmployeeDTO.getAddress());
        emsEmployee.setSecqn(emsEmployeeDTO.getSecqn());
        emsEmployee.setSecans(emsEmployeeDTO.getSecans());
        emsEmployee.setBsbid(emsEmployeeDTO.getBsbid());
        emsEmployee.setAccid(emsEmployeeDTO.getAccid());
        emsEmployee.setSalary(emsEmployeeDTO.getSalary());
        emsEmployee.setAppgroup(emsEmployeeDTO.getAppgroup());
        emsEmployee.setActive(emsEmployeeDTO.getActive());
        emsEmployee.setMemo(emsEmployeeDTO.getMemo());

        return emsEmployee;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean createRecord(EmsEmployeeDTO emsEmployeeDTO) {
        // try to find the database record in the database first
        EmsEmployee tmpEmployee = em.find(EmsEmployee.class, emsEmployeeDTO.getEmpid());

        if (tmpEmployee != null) {
            // employee whose empid can be found; should not add the record
            return false;
        }

        // employee whose empid could not be found; add it to the database
        try {
            // convert a DTO to DAO
            EmsEmployee emsEmployee = this.myDTO2DAO(emsEmployeeDTO);

            // add to database via JPA
            this.create(emsEmployee);

            return true;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // something is wrong, should not be here though
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: can you share source code piece?

Comment: EmsEmployee in particular

Comment: @tgdavies Thank you for your response, I've now attached it.

Comment: quite likely you are missing something in your configuration, but without further context, it's pretty hard to spot what.  But, isn't that class supposed to be populated based on your DB, instead of being instantiated with a 'new' ? Also: your equals method doesn't seem to make much sense, is that your actual equals method?

Comment: @Stultuske I've not actually edited any code with EmsEmployee - it was automatically generated with "New entity classes from Database". Did you need some more information regarding my configuration?

Comment: @JeremyChiang why do you try to instantiate it with the new keyword?

Comment: @Stultuske that was put in my lecturer and is used to convert the data transfer object to a data access object for ORM purposes. And that eventually gets passed into the EntityManager

Comment: What Java version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

You are using GlassFish 5.1.0 and this only supports Java 8.

I assume that you are using a newer Java version (probably 14) that causes this exception.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I'm currently using OpenJDK 8